# How to select the highest score in a text file row in python?

Tags: python

How can i select the highest score of each row in a text file containing x no of lines
the text file is laid out as

```
Richard 3 5 7
Bob 4 7 8
Jeff 3 3 5
```

ect.

For every line the highest number for each user must be set as a variable

I have based my code on this which finds the highest of an entire text file but it needs to be done for each line of the text file :

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r') 
data = f.readlines()
for range(2,...): 

    max(data)
    min(data)
print max(data), min(data
```

Comment: What have you tried already? We're happy to help when you get stuck, but please don't expect us to write all of the code for you.

Comment: sadly i lost the code it might be a pathetic excuse but please help no hate plz

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to happen. I'm sure you can take ten minutes to start over, and come back here if you run into problems. Have a nice day.

Comment: Get all the numbers: `/\w+(?: (\d+))+/g`...

Comment: what is that i dont understand that code

Comment: @Richard May not be the smartest approach to give those trying to help you attitude.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        spl = line.split()
        print("Highest score for {} is {}".format(spl[0],max(map(int,spl[1:]))))

Highest score for Richard is 7
Highest score for Bob is 8
Highest score for Jeff is 5
```

If you want particular columns using indexing:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        spl = line.split()
        print("Highest score for {} is {}".format(spl[0],max(map(int,spl[1]+spl[2]))))))


Highest score for Richard is 5
Highest score for Bob is 7
Highest score for Jeff is 3
```

Comment: is there any way the code can be altered so it only bases it on specified columns and sets it as a varaible?

Comment: what do you mean by  specified columns?

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be roughly this:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        nums_str = line.split()[1:]
        nums = [int(n) for n in nums_str]
        max_in_line = max(nums)
        min_in_line = min(nums)
```

- Using the `with ... as ...` syntax takes care of any exceptions and closes the file after reading it.
- In most cases it is better to iterate through the file line by line instead of reading all of it into memory in case the file is very large. You can just use `for line in f` to iterate through each line in the file.
- Some suggestions included using a regular expression to extract the numbers. However, it is way faster to split the line by whitespace, using `split()` function and take everything but the first element, using `[1:]` on the list that is returned by the `split()` function.
- The `split()` function returns a list of strings that represent numbers. That's why you need to cast them to `int` using a list comprehension. Then getting a min and max is trivial.